# Does Ubuntu install well on the Gateway NE56R31u? Are there any ceveats or things to watch out for?

Tags: installation, windows-8

Does Ubuntu install well on the Gateway NE56R31u? Are there any ceveats or things to watch out for? (Given the UEFI/Secureboot/Windows8 hassles...) Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu may be a bit laggy, due to the lack of an SSD, but Unity works fine on reasonably bad processors. (ask the person running ubuntu on an ssd-upgraded thinkpad x60 from 2006 :P) note: I don't own said laptop, so just guessing

Comment: @YetAnotherUser I was more worried about UEFI/Secureboot problems.

Comment: Micro$oft requires that it's possible to disable secureboot on windows 8 "certified" systems, so you could go poking around in the bios, I guess. I have had a couple bad experiences with notebook bioses, (you can't access any of the settings that *should* be there).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that there are brightness related problems that affect the Gateway NE56R41u, and I bet it affects your computer too. Boot Ubuntu live and see if the brightness keys work. If you see the bar moving but the brightness isn't changing, then you too are affected by this problem. However, that would be the only thing I would worry about. You shouldn't have any problems booting UEFI though.